# Merging datasets in Python on timestamp with emphasis on Date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, timestamp

I have a large dataset ('df'; ~400,000 lines) of rows with a datetime index describing features of cities.
eg.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['2016-01-01 00:00:00','Jacksonville'], ['2016-01-01 01:00:00','Jacksonville'], 
                  ['2016-01-01 02:00:00','Jacksonville'], ['2016-01-01 03:00:00','Toronto']], columns=['timestamp','City'])
```

I want to merge this with another smaller dataset I've created ('public_holidays'; ~300 lines) that lists public holidays for those cities.

eg.

```py
public_holidays = pd.DataFrame([['1/01/2016','New Year\'s Day','Jacksonville'], ['1/01/2016','New Year\'s Day','San Francisco'], 
                   ['25/12/2018','Christmas Day','Toronto'], ['26/12/2018','Boxing Day','Toronto']], columns=['timestamp','Holiday','City'])
```

Currently I've done this:

```py
new_df= pd.merge(df, public_holidays, how = 'left', on = ['timestamp','City'])
```

This works, however as 'df's timestamp contains every hour of each day, the merge only occures at the hour 00:00 (as 'public_holidays' "timestamp" is only by date).

How can I get `'public_holidays'` to map to every row that matches its date, regardless of time?

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to *df* an auxiliary column with normalized timestamp:

```
df['dat'] = df.timestamp.dt.normalize()
```

Then in merge, instead of *on=...* pass:

- left_on=['dat', 'City'],
- right_on=['timestamp', 'City'].

Finally (after the *new_df* is created) you can drop this auxiliary column.

An alternative is to overwrite *timestamp* column with the normalized *timestamp*:

```
df.timestamp = df.timestamp.dt.normalize()
```

and perform the merge without any change.

Note: As you failed to include sample data, the above advice is only
"theoretical", not supported by any actual test run.